# Trying to filter double-tap events through a UIView

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, touch-event, touchesbegan, uiresponder

In an iOS app, I have a UIWebView which I use to display some contents and to dismiss this UIWebView I use the following mechanism:

I put a DoubleTapView (subclass of UIView) on top of the UIWebView.

This DoubleTapView catches the double-tap events and executes adequate code to dimiss itself as well as the UIWebView.
Up to this point it works fine.

Here is the problem:
All the events that the UIWebView is interested in (scrolling the contents, tapping links ..etc..) don't go through; they are blocked by the DoubleTapView. How can I solve this?

In fact for what I just described I could have used a UIView instead of a DoubleTapView.
But I intended to subclass UIView with DoubleTapView. And then implement:
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
or
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
to solve my problem, but I must be doing something wrong, because it does not work (at list the way I did).

Here is some code I wrote to put the parts together:

```
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:varFrame];
    webView.delegate=self;
    quitGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(quitWeb:)];
    quitGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=2;
    varFrame.origin=CGPointZero;
    quitSensor=[[DoubleTapView alloc] initWithFrame:varFrame];
    quitSensor.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [quitSensor addGestureRecognizer:quitGesture];
    [webView addSubview:quitSensor];
```

and here is what I tried when implementing the methods for DoubleTapView:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self superview] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self superview] motionBegan:motion withEvent:event];
}
```